Next.js 14 loading.js Shows Navbar and Footer from layout.js
Problem: In my Next.js 14 application, I have a loading.js component intended solely to display a loading indicator. However, the Navbar and Footer components from the RootLayout inside the layout.js are also appearing when loading.js is rendered. I need the loading.js to display only the loading indicator without the navbar or footer.
Expected Behavior: The loading.js should only display a loading spinner when active. Other components like the navbar and footer should not be visible until the data is fully loaded and the main content begins to render.
Current Behavior: Despite its setup, the loading.js still displays the navbar and footer defined in RootLayout inside the layout.js.
layout.js
import "./globals.css";
import Footer from "@/components/Footer";
import Navbar from "@/components/nav-bar";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


loading.js
import Loader from "@/components/loader/loader";

export default function LoaderPage() {
  return <Loader />;
}


How can I modify the LoaderPage in loading.js or RootLayout in layout.js so that only the Loader is visible during loading, without the navbar and footer components without changing the component to client component?

Everything at the same level will be wrapped by the layout, it's expected.
The solution is to use Route Groups. Usually the root layout does not contain components but only providers because they affect the whole app.
But of course you may want to have a layout for the home page. To do that we need a route group. Your app will look like this:
src/
└── app/
    ├── (main)/
    │   ├── page.jsx # moved
    │   └── layout.jsx # navbar and footer here
    ├── layout.jsx # metadata here
    └── loading.jsx # same

The page.jsx inside (main) will be wrapped by the root layout and his sibling, and loading.jsx will be wrapped only by the root layout solving your problem (:
Result
#app/layout.jsx
import "./globals.css";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

#app/(main)layout.jsx
import Footer from "@/components/Footer";
import Navbar from "@/components/nav-bar";

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}


I tried this and right now the loader is not showing, and after I put a loading.js in the main route group the loader is shown with the footer and navbar.

Then you should try to create a Layout.tsx and wrap your page.tsx; The layout will always wrap the loader...

@Aflahvp I created a project to test and it worked fine. Maybe there's something missing in the question. One last thing i can think is to make the layout inside (main) a client component with "use client" directive.

does that make the whole website client side and loose the seo privileges of nextjs

@Aflahvp It does not. There's a complete explanation why in this answer

that's entirely a different scenario. we can wrap a server component with a client component and the server component remains server component, but if we add "use client" in a component and all of the components imported inside that component will change to client component.

And I tried as you mentioned and converted the component to client, but unfortunately the issue still there.
